# Phase plane for nonlinear Hamiltonian system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have Hamiltonian system 
$$
\begin{align}
 \dfrac {dx}{dt}=&y  \\
\dfrac {dy}{dt}=&5x^2+3x+7  
\end{align}
$$
I have found Hamiltonian which is
$$H(x,y)=-\dfrac {5x^3}3-\dfrac {3x^2}2+7x$$
I calculated the equilibrium points to be $(-1.52,0)$ and $(0.92,0)$
And I built phase plane

But I don’t understand what kind of phase plane is it. Is it a node? Center? Spiral?

[image]

Comment: The hamiltonian of the system is not correct

Comment: @Moo Yes, it's written correctly
So that's how I fond them: ∂H/∂y=0 and ∂H/∂x=-5x^2-3x+7
-5x^2-3x+7=0
So we have x=-1.52 and 0.92
Is it wrong?

Comment: The Hamiltonian of the system should be :$$H(x,y)=-\dfrac {5x^3}3-\dfrac {3x^2}2-7x+\frac {y^2}2 $$

Comment: @Aryadeva oh, thanks! But why is it +(y^2)/2 ?

Comment: Because you have from first equation that  $\partial_y H=y \implies H=y^2/2+ f(x)$

Comment: @Aryadeva got it! thank you! but aren't equilibrium points the same? (−1.52,0) and (0.92,0). From ∂H/∂y=y and ∂H/∂x=-5x^2-3x+7

Comment: You should check your work again since you had some mistakes and graph the system to see what is the nature of the equilibria Alison.

Comment: Are you sure your system is correct because the critical point are completely different https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x%5E2%2B3x%2B7%3D0

Comment: @Aryadeva you are right! Thank you! I have made some mistake. Critical points are: M1((-3-i√131)/10,0) and M2((-3+i√131)/10,0)
For the first equilibrium point the eigenvalues are λ1,2=±3.38*i^(3/2)
For the second equilibrium point the eigenvalues are λ1,2=±3.38*i^(1/2)
Is it a center?

Comment: You should graph the system to see it Alison.